# Pass a Function with multiple parameters as a Parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, func, stopwatch, measure

I have this piece of code, that takes a single function with no parameter, and return's its runtime.

```
public static Stopwatch With_StopWatch(Action action)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch;
}
```

I would like to transform it to take non void functions with parameters.
I heard about the Func<> delegate, but I have no idea how to use it.
And I need something like this (very pseudo) :

```
   public T measureThis(ref Stopwatch sw, TheFunctionToMeasure(parameterA,parameterB))
   {
       sw.Start(); // start stopwatch
       T returnVal = TheFunctionToMeasure(A,B); // call the func with the parameters
       stopwatch.Stop(); // stop sw
       return returnVal; // return my func's return val
   }
```

*So I have to get the return value of the passed func, AND get the stopwatch in the end.*
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original code can still work. How people will call it is what changes when you have parameters:

```
With_Stopwatch(MethodWithoutParameter);
With_Stopwatch(() => MethodWithParameters(param1, param2));
```

you can also call the method with parameters with the second syntax:

```
With_Stopwatch(() => MethodWithoutParameter());
With_Stopwatch(() => MethodWithParameters(param1, param2));
```

*Update*: if you want the return value, you can change your `measureThis` function to take a `Func<T>` instead of an Action:

```
public T measureThis<T>(Stopwatch sw, Func<T> funcToMeasure)
{
    sw.Start();
    T returnVal = funcToMeasure();
    sw.Stop();
    return returnVal;
}

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
int result = measureThis(sw, () => FunctionWithoutParameters());
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}, result: {1}", sw.Elapsed, result);
double result2 = meashreThis(sw, () => FuncWithParams(11, 22));
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}, result: {1}", sw.Elapsed, result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this technique, do I get the return value?

Comment: If you're interested in the return value then you should pass a `Func<T>` instead. I've edited the answer with info about it.